# I got error in android app: Unable to acquire context: EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW: A NativeWindowType argument does not refer to a valid native window

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I build unity3d and run it inside native android app. When I open native android dialog got error:
Unable to acquire context: EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW: A NativeWindowType argument does not refer to a valid native window.